Existence of Borel set and probability measure

Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^r$ and $Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^s$ random vectors and let $(X,Y)$ have probability density $f(x,y)$ with product measure $\mu \times \nu$ for $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $B(\mathbb{R}^r)$ and $B(\mathbb{R}^s)$.
Suppose there exist Borel sets $A$ and $B$ and positive number $\delta$ such that $\mu(A) > 0$ and $\nu(B) > 0$ and
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^r, \forall y \in B: f_{Y | X} (y | x) > 0, $$
$$ \forall x \in A, \forall y \in B: f_{Y | X} (y | x) \geq \delta, f_{X | Y} (x | y) \geq \delta.$$
Show that there exist: probability measure $\omega$ on $B(\mathbb{R}^r \times \mathbb{R}^s)$, positive number $\epsilon$ and Borel set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^r \times \mathbb{R}^s$, so that: $$\omega(E) = 1, $$ $$\forall x, \forall y : P^{(x,y)} (E) > 0$$ $$ \forall (x,y) \in E, \forall G \in B(\mathbb{R}^r \times \mathbb{R}^s) :  P^{(x,y)} (G) \geq \epsilon \omega(G)$$

I tried to take $\omega(G)= \int_G f(x,y) d\mu (x) d\nu(y)$ and $E = A \times B$, but I am already struggling to show that $\omega(E) =1$ so I am wondering if that is the right idea... I tried it like this:
$$ w(E) = \int_E f(x,y)  d\mu (x) d\nu(y) = \int_{x \in A} \int_{y \in B} f(x | y) f(y) d\mu (x) d\nu(y) \geq \delta \int_{x \in A} \int_{y \in B}  f(y) d\mu (x) d\nu(y)$$
I get stuck here. I would be very thankful for any ideas on how to continue or new suggestions / help on what to take for $\omega$ and $E$. After I am sure that I have chosen a good $E$ and $\omega$ i will continue to try to solve the next part....

$\omega$ is an unfortunate choice of notation for the probability measure, when it is typically used to indicate an element of $\Omega$.
